# ScrollView in Custom DIalog adds margin to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-scrollview

I'm creating a custom dialog with ScrollView inside it due to big amount of elements.

The problem is that ScrollView moves all the content to the top. Seems like it adds margin bottom. Therefore top content is cropped and bot content has too many free space when ScrollView is sliding to bottom. Please see screenshots.

1) When slided to top content is cropped.

[image]

2)When slided to bottom content has margin

[image]

That's how it should look like:

[image]

**Code code:**
dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/pop_margin_outer">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_rectangle"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ll_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ll_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/ll_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/ll_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ll_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/ll_content"/>

<include layout="@layout/content_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_48"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_48"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_dialog_close"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_x_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_x_size"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_x"
    android:layout_above="@id/view_bg"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/view_bg"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/view_bg"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/item_padding_small"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/item_padding_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/item_padding_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/item_padding_small"
    />
```

**Code code:** dialog_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_24"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_24"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_24"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_36">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_headline"
            style="@style/yellow_text_middle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_24"
            android:text="@string/db_headline"
            android:textSize="@dimen/middle_text_min" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/yellow_text_small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/db_content_1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
                style="@style/yellow_text_small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="@dimen/middle_text_min" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            style="@style/yellow_text_small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_24"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/db_content_2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/small_logo"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_24"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/teal_text_small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_24"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/db_content_3" />

        <include layout="@layout/content_broker_input" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
            style="@style/btn_bg_yellow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pop_space_vertical_24"
            android:text="@string/db_btn_continue" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Any ideas why ScrollView has this behavior?**

Comment: Add this property in `Scroll View` `android:fillViewport="true"` and check.

Comment: Added. Nothing changed :(